# undefined reference - portaudio

Tags: c++, reference, cmake, portaudio

An issue I am having with this cmake list, is that I am getting error message  `error: undefined reference to 'Pa_GetVersion'`
for this piece of code:

record.cpp:

```
#include "record.h"

record::record()
{
    std::cout << "Record Created!" << std::endl;
}

void record::example()
{
    std::cout << "In example!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << Pa_GetVersion();
}
```

record.h

```
#ifndef RECORD_H
#define RECORD_H
#include <iostream>
#include "portaudio.h"
class record
{
public:
    record();
    void example();
};

#endif // RECORD_H
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "record.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    record test;
    test.example();

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```cmake
project(audio)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
#include externalproject {portaudio} if lib/portaudio don't exist.
INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(project_portaudio
    GIT_REPOSITORY      https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git
    PREFIX              lib/portaudio
    UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   <SOURCE_DIR>/configure
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE     1
    BUILD_COMMAND       make
    INSTALL_COMMAND     sudo make install
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio SOURCE_DIR)

SET(portaudio_lib_dir "${BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs")
SET(portaudio_inc_dir "${SOURCE_DIR}/include")


#IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
#   SET(EXTRA_LIBS rt m asound  pthread)
#ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")

#Add the files in the source list
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

#Add portaudio library
ADD_LIBRARY(portaudio STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET portaudio PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${portaudio_lib_dir}/libportaudio.a")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST} ${portaudio_inc_dir})

#What to compile before target!
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}  project_portaudio)

#What libraries to link to the target!
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} portaudio)
project(audio)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
#include externalproject {portaudio} if lib/portaudio don't exist.
INCLUDE(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(project_portaudio
    GIT_REPOSITORY      https://git.assembla.com/portaudio.git
    PREFIX              lib/portaudio
    UPDATE_COMMAND      ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND   <SOURCE_DIR>/configure
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE     1
    BUILD_COMMAND       make
    INSTALL_COMMAND     sudo make install
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio BINARY_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(project_portaudio SOURCE_DIR)

SET(portaudio_lib_dir "${BINARY_DIR}/lib/.libs")
SET(portaudio_inc_dir "${SOURCE_DIR}/include")


#IF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")
#   SET(EXTRA_LIBS rt m asound  pthread)
#ENDIF(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Linux")

#Add the files in the source list
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

#Add portaudio library
ADD_LIBRARY(portaudio STATIC IMPORTED)
SET_PROPERTY(TARGET portaudio PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${portaudio_lib_dir}/libportaudio.a")
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST} ${portaudio_inc_dir})

#What to compile before target!
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}  project_portaudio)

#What libraries to link to the target!
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} portaudio)
```

which code wise should not be possible as the files needed exist.. and in the CMakeList added... So I don't see the problem.

**Update**

Changed some things,  the new error I am getting is:

```
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_linux_alsa.o): In function `PaAlsaStream_WaitForFrames':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:3792: undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_linux_alsa.o): In function `CallbackThreadFunc':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:4197: undefined reference to `__pthread_register_cancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:4202: undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:4240: undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:4365: undefined reference to `__pthread_unregister_cancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:4365: undefined reference to `__pthread_unregister_cancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:4365: undefined reference to `__pthread_unregister_cancel'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_linux_alsa.o): In function `PaAlsa_LoadLibrary':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:380: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_open'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:381: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:382: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_nonblock'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:383: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_frames_to_bytes'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:384: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_prepare'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:385: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_start'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:386: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_resume'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:387: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_wait'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:388: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_state'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:389: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_avail_update'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:390: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_areas_silence'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:391: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_mmap_begin'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:392: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_mmap_commit'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:393: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_readi'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:394: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_readn'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:395: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_writei'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:396: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_writen'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:397: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_drain'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:398: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_recover'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:399: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_drop'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:400: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_area_copy'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:401: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_poll_descriptors'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:402: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_poll_descriptors_count'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:403: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_poll_descriptors_revents'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:404: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_format_size'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:405: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_link'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:406: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_delay'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:408: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:409: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:410: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_free'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:411: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_any'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:412: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:413: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:414: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:416: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:417: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:418: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_resample'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:420: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:421: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:422: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_min'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:424: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:425: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_periods_integer'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:426: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_periods_min'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:428: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:433: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_min'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:434: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_channels_max'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:436: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_period_size'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:437: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_format'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:438: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_access'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:439: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_dump'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:440: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:442: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_periods_min'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:443: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_periods_max'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:444: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:445: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size_min'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:446: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size_max'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:447: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size_max'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:448: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_min'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:449: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_max'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:450: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_numden'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:452: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_sizeof'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:453: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_malloc'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:454: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_current'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:455: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_avail_min'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:456: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:457: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_free'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:458: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_start_threshold'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:459: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_stop_threshold'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:460: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_get_boundary'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:461: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_threshold'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:462: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_silence_size'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:463: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_xfer_align'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:464: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_mode'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:466: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:467: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_sizeof'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:468: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_malloc'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:469: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_free'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:470: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_set_device'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:471: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_set_subdevice'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:472: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_set_stream'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:473: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_get_name'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:474: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_info_get_card'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:476: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_pcm_next_device'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:477: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_pcm_info'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:478: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_open'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:479: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_close'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:480: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_malloc'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:481: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_free'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:482: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:483: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_sizeof'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:484: undefined reference to `snd_ctl_card_info_get_name'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:486: undefined reference to `snd_config'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:487: undefined reference to `snd_config_update'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:488: undefined reference to `snd_config_search'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:489: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_entry'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:490: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_first'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:491: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_end'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:492: undefined reference to `snd_config_iterator_next'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:493: undefined reference to `snd_config_get_string'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:494: undefined reference to `snd_config_get_id'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:495: undefined reference to `snd_config_update_free_global'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:497: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:498: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_sizeof'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:499: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_tstamp'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:500: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_state'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:501: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_trigger_tstamp'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:502: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_status_get_delay'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:504: undefined reference to `snd_card_next'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:505: undefined reference to `snd_asoundlib_version'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:506: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c:507: undefined reference to `snd_output_stdio_attach'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_oss.o): In function `PaOSS_AudioThreadProc':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1620: undefined reference to `__pthread_register_cancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1641: undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1676: undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1759: undefined reference to `sem_post'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_oss.o): In function `PaOssStream_WaitForFrames':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1336: undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1370: undefined reference to `pthread_testcancel'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_oss.o): In function `PaOSS_AudioThreadProc':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1770: undefined reference to `__pthread_unregister_cancel'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_oss.o): In function `StartStream':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:1813: undefined reference to `sem_wait'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_oss.o): In function `PaOssStream_Terminate':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:920: undefined reference to `sem_destroy'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_oss.o): In function `PaOssStream_Initialize':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/hostapi/oss/pa_unix_oss.c:902: undefined reference to `sem_init'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_util.o): In function `PaUtil_StartThreading':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c:184: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_util.o): In function `PaUtil_CancelThreading':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c:205: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c:203: undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_util.o): In function `PaUnixThread_Terminate':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c:441: undefined reference to `pthread_join'
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c:437: undefined reference to `pthread_cancel'
lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/lib/.libs/libportaudio.a(pa_unix_util.o): In function `PaUnixThread_New':
/home/lambda/soundcloud/audio/lib/portaudio/src/project_portaudio/src/os/unix/pa_unix_util.c:305: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [audio] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/audio.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: What version of PortAudio are you using? `Pa_CountDevices` doesn't appear to exist in the latest version.

Comment: hmm.. interesting, my version of portaudio.h does have that function..

Comment: my version of portaudio.h seems different from the one located in the repo...

Comment: @aschepler it seems like I have two version of portaudio.h, one located within the project, and one at /usr/local/include/portaudio.h, which is why the one i used had that function.. But the path hardcoded in the code is for the one wihthin the project. I worked with pyaudio before, I guess that might be the reason why two of the same file exist.

Comment: Nevertheless, I still have the same issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CMake script does not seem to contain a 'target_link_libraries' line, to instruct it to link your project executable against the portaudio library. The 'add_dependencies' line just makes sure portaudio is built first, it does not actually link against it.

Try adding something like the following:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}  portaudio)
```

Comment: Where do you want me to place it in the cmakelist?

Comment: Looks like you also need to link against pthreads, and from what I can tell the snd_* functions are from ALSA so you may need to link against that also.

Comment: I added this line.. `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME}  ${EXTRA_LIBS} portaudio)` and set `EXTRA_LIBS` as 
   `SET(EXTRA_LIBS rt m asound  pthread)`... So it should be linked..

Comment: These are the error messages I am getting... 
https://pastebin.com/mGDfiHgU